# Is the code formatting broken?

Tags: support

As far as I can tell, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879291/generate-iis-application-key-programmatically/31888828#31888828) has its code properly formatted yet it displays as plain text to me. I even tried editing it to fix it but it still displayed as plain text. Is the code formatting broken?

I tried it on Chrome 44 and IE 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An additional level of indenting is required inside bulleted lists, 8 spaces instead of the usual 4. I've fixed the formatting in the answer.